# Receber dados em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Tenho uma dúvida muito vil sobre JavaScript, mas acredito que vão me entender, uma vez que sou novato na linguagem.

Seguinte:

Criei uma página em html onde o usuário vai ter 5 opções de serviços para escolher, certo? Certo!

Quando o usuário clicar no serviço escolhido ele será direcionado a página seguinte, que será a mesma independente da escolha do usuário. E é aqui que entra minha dúvida.

Quero saber como mostrar na página seguinte apenas a escolha que o usuário selecionou. Sei fazer isso em PHP, onde eu recebo com o `$_POST['nome_do_campo_html']` e atribuo a uma variável, mas preciso fazer isso em JavaScript.

Comment: Olá, uma pergunta semelhante [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) foi respondida e espero que te ajude

Comment: O conteúdo específico para cada seleção vem do PHP? porque não mudas o pedaço da página específico em vez de carregar a página de novo?

Answer (score 2):

Pega a URL usando:

```
var url = window.location;
```

Depois usa o `split` para separar por `?`. Separa o domínio dos parâmetros.

Depois faz um `split` no resultado [1], agora com `&` para ter cada um dos parâmetros separados. Mais ou menos assim:

```
var parametrosDaUrl = url.split("?")[1];
var listaDeParametros = parametrosDaUrl.split("&");
```

Comment: Seria bom tirar o fragmento # da URL antes de pegar os parâmetros, e checar se a query tem um valor verdadeiro antes de separar os parâmetros

Answer (score 0):

Me baseei um pouco na resposta de @SergioBarros.

Essa solução vai, antes de pegar os parâmetros do URL, tirar o fragmento dele, depois pegar a lista de parâmetros, e por fim construir um objeto de parâmetros. Todos os parâmetros serão guardados nesse objeto se a query `?` existe.

No final, para ler os parâmetros do URL basta indexar o objeto `params`, assim como você indexa `$_POST` no PHP!

```
params["nome_do_campo_html"];
params.nome_do_campo_html;
```

---

```
var url = location.href;

// Ignora o fragmento da URL
var noFrag = url.split('#')[0];

// Pega a lista de parâmetros
var query = noFrag.split('?')[1];

// Cria um objeto
// para guardar os parâmetros
var params = {};

// Checa se a lista de parâmetros
// existe
if (query) {
    // Faz a separação dos parâmetros
    let offParams = query.split('&');

    // Vamos iterar os parâmetros!
    for (let param of offParams) {
        // Checa se o parâmetro não está vázio
        if (param.length) {
            // Pega a índice do '='
            let assignIndex = param.indexOf('=');
            let key, value;

            // Checa se o '=' existe
            if (assignIndex >= 0) {
                // Pega o nome do parâmetro
                key = param.substring(0, assignIndex);
                // Pega o valor (depois de '=')
                value = param.substring(assignIndex + 1) || true;
            } else {
                // O nome do parâmetro...
                // realmente pertence à @param.
                key = param;
                // O valor padrão será true
                value = true;
            }

            // Por fim guardamos o parâmetro
            // no objeto params
            params[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Ah! E outra alternativa é usar a interface `URLSearchParams` para interpretar a query do URL e usar o método `URLSearchParams#get` para ler um parâmetro:

```
var noFrag = location.href.split('#')[0];
var urlQuery = noFrag.split('?')[1];

if (urlQuery) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(urlQuery);

    // Exemplo de uso !
    var myParam = searchParams.get('nome');
}
```

Essa interface é implementada em navegadores atuais.